# Ignoring exception in oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table with some denormalized precalculated columns that are maintained by a trigger. The data sometimes is corrupted and the process fails but in these cases I need just ignore the exceptions and continue because it is not important to catch the error.

How can I write the exception clause to just go on without raising any error when an exception ocurrs?

I've tried just leaving the clause empty:

```
...
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN


end test_trigger;
```

but it does not compile.

What am I missing? there is some "pass" clause that I should be including?

Comment: "WHEN OTHERS THEN {do nothing}" is a very bad idea. Any error might occur (including some errors that you might want to know about) and you'll never know. You may as well save time and not have the precalc columns set at all. You should work out what kinds of exceptions might occur in the normal course of work and handle them explicitly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
...
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        NULL;

end test_trigger;
```